# Get a list of missing hotfixes for windows

Tags: windows, patch-management

How to get a list of all available patches/hotfixes for any given Windows platform? What I would like to do is:

- Get a list of already deployed patches (using something like wmic qfe list full /format:htable >C:\hotfixes.htm)
- Get a list of all available patches for that platform

Compare the two to see if anything of importance is missing.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Why not use WSUS? It seems overkill to roll your own solution when WSUS is free and already does this plus more (not much more, but some).

Comment: @john-homer Not everything has a WSUS attached to it. Think of stand-alone installations.

Comment: I know this is old, but I've been away. WSUS works with standalone (workgroup) hosts as well. You just have to manually set the registry entries instead of having Group Policy push them out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think I'd care about knowing the difference, I'd just make sure that you are periodically hitting a wsus server of some sort download/install/reboot monthly...  Other then that I've used http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc  with a -whatif and it kinda gives you the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running a Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer scan on the system - it'll report on missing updates.

Download it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923).

Comment: forgot about this tool good answer.

Comment: So new visitors know, unfortunately this tool has been discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

If you have PowerShell, such a query is fairly simple.

```
Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from win32_quickfixengineering'
```

PowerShell is installed by default in modern Windows, and you can download for older ones such as Windows XP.

Comment: he already has that portion done, doesn't tell him what he needs.

Comment: OP asked: How to get a list of all available patches/hotfixes for any given Windows platform? I don't think PS can do this.

Comment: yes powershell can get the list of AVAILABLE patches its just not a simple wmi call, see my post.

Comment: That's awesome Tony! It appears someone has already done all of the heavy lifting. It should be a simple matter to put together a script that does exactly what he's asking for using this module. I'll see if I can't find some spare time and whip something up.